# Has there ever been a complete game in which the pitcher never threw 3 balls in one at-bat?

Tags: baseball, history, mlb

During his perfect game in Game 5 of the 1956 World Series, Don Larsen went to 3 balls in a count against only one batter. ([source](https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/mlb/2020/01/01/don-larsen-dies-obit-perfect-game-world-series-yankees/1916513/))

Has there ever been a complete game in MLB history in which the pitcher never threw 3 balls during one at-bat?  (Meaning that the count against any one batter never reached 3-0, 3-1, or 3-2.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per an SI [article,](https://archive.ph/20130102072625/http://vault.sportsillustrated.cnn.com/vault/article/magazine/MAG1124496/index.htm) [Len Barker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Len_Barker) did not allow three balls to anyone in his 1981 [perfect game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Len_Barker%27s_perfect_game).

> He struck out 11 batters—all swinging—and didn't go to a single three-ball count. Only eight Toronto batters got as much as a two-ball count.